# While downloading file from URL it is adding local directory path in URL

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download file but facing one issue.

File path I am fetching from database -- table and it looks like this.

```
https://testupload.blob.core.windows.net/files/guid/795.pdf
```

Now when I am fetching this path and passing to download then it is automatically add my local drive path in URL and it looks like this

```
E:\Projects\testporject\https://testupload.blob.core.windows.net/files/guid/795.pdf
```

I am trying using this code..

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("https://testupload.blob.core.windows.net/files/guid/795.pdf",
                    @"..\\projectname\\filedownload\\975.pdf");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

any idea or help on this..

Comment: The local path is invalid. You're using a verbatim string so `@"..\\projectname\\filedownload"` specifies a path with 4 backslashes.